# How to navigate between different html pages in Windows 8 Metro application using javascript?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can i navigate between different html pages using javascript? 
I tried to use the below statement but it's not working. I have added a breakpoint and found that  the below statement is executed.But still It doesn't display the `page2.html`.

`WinJS.Navigation.navigate("page2.html", null);`

Can anyone tell me why in what all scenarios it won't work ? 
One option I found was iframe which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Am also facing the same issue.Can anyone give me some helpful info to send values/object between pages as well as working on navigation?

Answer (score 1):

This API isn't a specific page navigator; it's about loading the location as defined by the location service in WinJS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx has the details on the specifics of using that model.

That stated, if you wish to use the normal Web model of a new page, either a normal link, or setting the window.location to the other page will cause a browser navigate.