# WinJS Share Target Redirect

Tags: windows-8, winjs

In WinJS is it possible to redirect a page once it has been activated by using the share charm?

So my target page is /pages/target/target.html.  In the .js I want to do something like;

`WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/anotherpage/anotherpage.html");`

It doesn't seem to raise an error but it's not navigating away from the target page.

I want to redirect pages based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to another question:
[How to navigate between different html pages in Windows 8 Metro application using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559490/how-to-navigate-between-different-html-pages-in-windows-8-metro-application-usin/11563958#11563958)

However, if you actually are performing a page navigation (e.g. window.location changes), then you're going to have the challenge that the activation info with the share stuff will not be available; your script context is torn down on a page navigation, so you won't be able to hold onto it easily.

Comment: Ahh maybe it's the activation code I will try adding that in both pages.

Comment: I did manage to get round the problem by rendering fragments but it does mean a big rewrite.

Comment: You could always handle activation event, save the information you need to perform the share, and then do the navigation. Are you using a different html file for the share contract? That allows you to specify a diff. Html file for the to use when you are the share target.